# Automatically fill out new columns based on unique values of a separate column

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of items where each item is represented in a row and the info of each item is represented in the columns. One of these columns, for example, is "Size"

Elsewhere in the sheet I'd like to keep some statistics of the list of items, one of those being the number of items of each size. This is easy to do with COUNT, though I would need to manually update this summary list each time a new size (for ex) is included in the list, where it wasn't before

Is there a way for this summary list to auto-populate the next column when a new size is found?

For example, say I have a list of items

```
#   Name        Size
01  James       M
02  John        L
03  Jill        S
04  Jacob       L
05  Julie       S
```

The summary list elsewhere would look like

```
Size     S     M     L
Count    2     1     2
```

But if I add a new item to the list

```
06   Jeremy      XL
```

The summary should auto update to include this not-seen-before size, in a new column

```
Size     S     M     L     XL
Count    2     1     2      1
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Look into Pivot tables

Answer (score 1):

With MS365, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(x,DROP(TOCOL(C:C,3),1),y,SORTBY(x,x,-1,LEN(x),),HSTACK({"Size";"Count"},PIVOTBY(,y,y,ROWS,0,,,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach in Google Sheets:

```
=let(
sizes,{"XS";"S";"M";"L";"XL"},
tbl,{{"Size","Count"};{sizes,map(sizes,lambda(each,countif(C:C,each)))}},
transpose(query(tbl,"where Col2>0",1)))
```